# Работа с полями и методами объекта java script

Tags: javascript, объекты

есть вот такой вот код:

```js
class Book {
  constructor() {
    this.param1 = 1;
    this.param2 = [];
    this.param3 = this.summ();
  }
  summ() {
    console.log(`summ started`);
    let a = 0;
    this.param2.forEach((obj) => {
      a += obj.val
    });
    return a
  }
  addArray(obj) {
    this.param2.push(obj)
  }

}
let arr = [{
  val: 1
}, {
  val: 2
}, {
  val: 3
}, ];
let book = new Book();
book.addArray(arr);
console.log(book.param3);
```

Не могу понять, из-за чего, третий параметр - ndefined... 
В случае, если метод возвращает сумму значений параметров - все ок... 
Как забороть ?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `param3` вычисляется здесь:

```
let book = new Book();
```

и не обновляется после вызова

```
book.addArray(arr);
```

---

```
  addArray(obj) {
    obj.forEach(el => this.param2.push(el));
    this.param3 = this.summ();
  }
```

```js
class Book {
  constructor() {
    this.param1 = 1;
    this.param2 = [];
    this.param3 = this.summ();
  }
  summ() {
    console.log(`summ started`);
    let a = 0;
    this.param2.forEach((obj) => {
      a += obj.val
    });
    return a
  }
  addArray(obj) {
    obj.forEach(el => this.param2.push(el));
    this.param3 = this.summ();
  }

}
let arr = [
  { val: 1 }, 
  { val: 2 },
  { val: 3 }
];
let book = new Book();
book.addArray(arr);
console.log(book.param3);
```

Comment: Сделал, так как вы предложили, теперь выдает NaN. Да и в любом случае ,конструкция странная получается....  Может есть какой-либо принятый метод записи, вычисления параметра (когда это нужно)

Comment: @NikolayBarda Не знаю, почему Вы свойство объекта называете "параметром" и что в этом коде странного, но, раз уж Вы используете классы, объявите `param3` как свойство и вычисляйте его значение в гетере.

Answer (score 1):

Реализуйте поле через getter:

```js
class Book {
    constructor() {
        this.param1 = 1;
        this.param2 = [];
    }

    get param3() {
        console.log(`summ started`);
        let result = this.param2.reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur.val, 0);
        return result;
    }

    addArray(obj) {
        this.param2.push(...obj);
    }
}

let arr = [{
    val: 1
}, {
    val: 2
}, {
    val: 3
}];

let book = new Book();
book.addArray(arr);
console.log(book.param3);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. И за reduce.